# How to deal with a Dataframe with many columns and if statement

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe, if-statement

Here is my problem

You will find below a sample of my DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['01/03/2000','01/04/2000','01/05/2000','01/06/2000','01/07/2000','01/08/2000'],
                      'Paul_Score':[3,10,22,32,20,40],
                       'John_Score':[8,42,10,57,3,70]

                      })

df['Date']= pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

df = df.set_index('Date')
```

And I started to work on a loop with an If statement like this:

```
def test(selection,symbol):
    df_end = (selection*0)
    rolling_mean = selection.rolling(2).mean().fillna(0)
    calendar = pd.Series(df_end.index)

    for date in calendar:
        module=1/selection.loc[date,symbol]
        if  selection.loc[date,symbol] > rolling_mean.loc[date,symbol]:
            df_end.loc[date,symbol] = module

        else:
            df_end.loc[date,symbol]=0


    return df_end
```

Then :

```
test(df,'John_Score')
```

However, my problem is that I don't know how to deal with many columns at the same time, my goal is to try this function on the whole dataframe (for all columns). This sample has only 2 columns but in reality I have 30 columns and I don't know how to do it.

EDIT :

This is what I have with `test(df,'John_Score')` :

```
       Paul_Score John_Score
Date        
2000-01-03  0   0.125000
2000-01-04  0   0.023810
2000-01-05  0   0.000000
2000-01-06  0   0.017544
2000-01-07  0   0.000000
2000-01-08  0   0.014286
```

And this is what I have with `test(df,'Paul_Score')` :

```
           Paul_Score John_Score
Date        
2000-01-03  0.333333    0
2000-01-04  0.100000    0
2000-01-05  0.045455    0
2000-01-06  0.031250    0
2000-01-07  0.000000    0
2000-01-08  0.025000    0
```

And I would like something like that :

```
          Paul_Score John_Score
Date        
2000-01-03  0.333333    0.125000
2000-01-04  0.100000    0.023810
2000-01-05  0.045455    0.000000
2000-01-06  0.031250    0.017544
2000-01-07  0.000000    0.000000
2000-01-08  0.025000    0.014286
```

My goal is to check df every day each column and if the value is greater than the value of its rolling mean 2 days then we compute 1/value of df if it is true and 0 if not.

It may have a simpler way but I'm trying to enhance my coding skills on for/if statement and I found that I have difficulties in doing computation on Dataframes with many columns

If you have any idea, you are welcome

Comment: Please provide details on what you want to do specifically, and what your expected output is. See the SO question posting guidlines at [ask]

Comment: Can you explain the test function in words?  I suspect you are trying to accomplish that can be done in a much simplier way.

Comment: Can you please give us a sample of expected output

Comment: Thanks for you answers, I made an Edit with the outcome that I expect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this code does the job:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['01/03/2000','01/04/2000','01/05/2000','01/06/2000','01/07/2000','01/08/2000'],
                      'Paul_Score':[3,10,22,32,20,40],
                       'John_Score':[8,42,10,57,3,70]

                      })

df['Date']= pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

df = df.set_index('Date')

def test(selection,symbol):
    df_end = (selection*0)
    rolling_mean = selection.rolling(2).mean().fillna(0)
    calendar = pd.Series(df_end.index)

    for date in calendar:
        for cols in symbol:
            module=1/selection.loc[date,cols]
            if  selection.loc[date,cols] > rolling_mean.loc[date,cols]:
                df_end.loc[date,cols] = module

            else:
                df_end.loc[date,cols]=0


    return df_end

test(df,['Paul_Score', 'John_Score'])
```

Output:

```
            Paul_Score  John_Score
Date                              
2000-01-03    0.333333    0.125000
2000-01-04    0.100000    0.023810
2000-01-05    0.045455    0.000000
2000-01-06    0.031250    0.017544
2000-01-07    0.000000    0.000000
2000-01-08    0.025000    0.014286
```

Comment: It does perfectly the trick, thank you @Andrea. Just if we have more than just 2 columns maybe `test(df,list(df.columns))` would be prefer. Thank you so much!